# ruby script\generate controller NOT WORKING

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following [this tutorial](http://oreilly.com/pub/a/ruby/archive/rails.html?page=2) and I've run the command `ruby script\server` and successfully started the server.

Now, when I run `ruby script\generate controller MyTest`, it says

```
'ruby' is not recognized as an internal or external command..
```

Comment: Are you in Windows? I've not once seen backslashes outside of the Windows environment, but I'm also surprised that you're not required to type, like, `ruby.exe`

Comment: Can you give the URL of the tutorial you are using (if it s an online tutorial)?

Comment: http://oreilly.com/pub/a/ruby/archive/rails.html?page=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message means

- you dont' have ruby installed (It's on page 1 of your tutorial)

or

- ruby is not in your PATH . In that case, check if the PATH points to the folder where you have installed ruby (on Windows I think it's PATH)

Edit:

If you look at the screenshots of the 1st page, the path to ruby is specified all the time 
`"c:\ruby\bin\ruby.exe" "c:\ruby\bin\gem" install rails`

I did install it on my netbook - I specified to update my PATH but it didnt. After setting up my path correctly, I could type: `gem install rails`

Comment: hum That's what I was wondering too. If you could run 'rails cookbook', then it's there . Sorry for the noise

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you either haven't installed ruby or it hasn't been added to your PATH environment variable. Use the [link text](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) from this page and make sure you open the cmd.exe console AFTER you installed Ruby.